# Screen squashed to the left half, black on the right half

Tags: display

Windows 7 Acer Aspire M3802

When I start up Windows the BIOS and boot screen show but the login screen doesn't, I just get a blank screen. The BIOS and boot screens are compacted over to one side (the left) and the right half is just black.
If I start up in safe mode, I can see the boot, login and desktop but they're all squashed over to the left. I can't move the mouse over to the right hand side.

Troubleshooting I've tried:

- Alternative monitor
- Alternative VGA cable
- Reinstalling video drivers
- Changing resolution

And here's where it gets interesting... I put in a Linux live CD and the boot screen is still squashed, but the desktop comes up fine, full screen.

I have the option of a clean install of Windows 8 but I'm not sure that it'll have any effect since when I boot from that CD, the screen is still squashed to the left.

Any ideas would be gratefully received.

Comment: Just for clarification: when you tried a different monitor and cable and such, did the problem remain or not? PS: If it's an Aspire then is an Acer, not an Asus.

Comment: This must be an issue with your Video driver. Uninstall the video driver and check it with default video driver and know your results. If the default driver works perfectly then check for updated graphic driver from the vendor site and update it.

Comment: It sounds like it could have something to do with the BIOS. Have you tried resetting the BIOS? If not http://www.wikihow.com/Reset-Your-BIOS

Comment: Get yourself up to speed on accessing the monitor's user controls - the one you want to get to is the "Auto" button: [Acer P205H manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/1072/Acer-P205h.html?page=14#manual). Press the Auto button to get the monitor to adjust its timings to fit the video signal, which should enable it to give the correct image.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It'd be hilarious if it was just the LCD not being aligned to the analog signal. :) Sounds plausible, but I'd be surprised though since he states he tried more than one monitor, and also multiple resolutions, but hey, you never know. ;)

Comment: The issue was the same across all combinations of monitors and cables. The "Auto" monitor control didn't resolve it unfortunately. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it does it in the BIOS then it's not a software issue, replace your video adapter.  If you're using an integrated video adapter, then you will need to replace the motherboard.

Comment: I think you're right. However, the part that puzzles me is that he said it works when he boots in linux. How is that possible?

Comment: @imtheman Because not all video modes use the same parts/resources of the video adapter.  I've seen it many times where there's text-mode corruption on cards but the graphical modes still work fine (and vise versa).

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's an onboard adapter - could I just add a new video card instead of replacing the entire motherboard?